# VueJs templating. How to load external templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, vue.js

I'm new to Vue.js, I've used AngularJS for some time and in angular we used to load templates such as,

```
template: '/sometemplate.html',
controller: 'someCtrl'
```

How can we do such a thing in Vue, instead of keeping large HTML templates inside JavaScript like this,

```
new Vue({
  el: '#replace',
  template: '<p>replaced</p>'
})
```

This is OK for small templates but for large templates is this practical?

Is there a way to load external template HTML or use HTML template inside a script tag like in Vue?

```
<script type="x-template" id="template">HTML template goes here</html>
```

Comment: What a bummer...

Comment: so basically vuejs is pure fad

Comment: This question was asked in 2015, meaning vue 1, and already had a solution, now we are at vue 3 which is anything but "fad"

Answer (score 34):

You can use the script tag template by just referring to its `id`.

```
{
  template: '#some-id'
}
```

Though, I highly recommend using <s>[vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify) (if you use browserify) or</s> [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) (if you use webpack) so you can have your components stored in nice little `.vue` files like this.

[image: vue file]

Also, the author of Vue wrote a nice post about the topic of external template urls:

https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/

Comment: Can you set the language of the template to something like Slim or Haml the same way that you can set `lang='sass'` in the the `<style>` element? If so, are there additional dependencies to get transpilation working?

Comment: Answered my own question. Supported engines are [found here](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/#supported-template-engines)

Comment: The only valuable argument in that blog post is the one about number of requests. The rest are opinions and bs. Use .vue to have proper syntax highlight ? I had proper syntax highlight BEFORE I had to use .vue files.

Comment: Doesn't the point made in "why no template url" basically make micro-frontends an impossibility?

Comment: @NicuSurdu actually that's exactly what makes Angular so bloaty and heavy. I agree it's easier for the dev, but the client suffers a lot.

Comment: [Most recent version of blog on wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210924092049/https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/)  since it is now missing from the vuejs site itself.

Answer (score 21):

You can try this:
for Vue2 : https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader
for Vue3 : https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader

**Example (Vue2) :**

```
 new Vue({
        components: {
            'my-component': httpVueLoader('my-component.vue')
        },
        ...
```

**Example (Vue3) :**

```
Vue.createApp({
  components: {
    'my-component': Vue.defineAsyncComponent(() => loadModule('./myComponent.vue', opts))
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Not recommended to use in production, unfortunately. Looks like using `npm` and `webpack` is the only choice.

Comment: ...is the recommended choice, not the only choice

Comment: Well, if you, as a creator of this plugin, think so I will give it a try.

Answer (score 16):

David, that is a nice example, but what's the best way to make sure the DOM is compiled?

https://jsfiddle.net/q7xcbuxd/35/

When I simulate an async operation, like in the example above, it works. But as soon as I load an external page "on the fly", Vue complains because the DOM is not ready.
More specifically:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'vue' of undefined`
Is there a better way to do this than to call `$compile` when the page has loaded? I've tried with `$mount`, but that didn't help.

**UPDATE:**
Never mind, I finally figured out how to do it:

```
Vue.component('async-component', function (resolve, reject) {
    vue.$http.get('async-component.html', function(data, status, request){
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
        resolve({
            template: doc
        });
    });
});
```

And in the actual template, I removed the

```
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-template"></script>
```

tags and only included the html.

(This solution requires the http loader from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.10/vue-resource.min.js)

Answer (score 9):

I've tried [http-vue-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) and it works fine.
This library is easy to use and has good documentation and [examples](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader#examples)

Although you can't load templates from filed directly you still can keep html in separate single-file components. You can even skip `<script>...</script>` part.

### Usage (from loader's documentation)

`my-component.vue`

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">Hello {{who}}</div>
</template>
```

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="my-app">
      <my-component></my-component>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Vue({
        el: '#my-app',
        components: {
          'my-component': httpVueLoader('my-component.vue')
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Both files should be placed in one folder at the same level

Answer (score 4):

### 1. In Vue 2.x I recommend sticking with convention by using .vue files but instead, inverting the order of imports:

```
// template.vue
<template>
  <div class="helloworld">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import src from './src'
  export default src
</script>
```

and in a separate file

```
// src.js
export default {
  name: 'helloworld',
  props: {},
  ...
}
```

Then in your component registration

```
import helloworld from './helloworld/template.vue'

new Vue({
 components: {
 'helloworld': helloworld
},
...})
```

This way you get the best of both worlds and you don't have to force yourself to build templates within a string.

### 2. If you want to lazy load, apparently there is a way to do so in Vue 2.x

```
new Vue({
 components: {
 'helloworld': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "helloworld" */ './helloworld/template.vue')
},
...})
```

This will load helloworld.js (which will contain all that component's code) on request of that page in the browser.

*Of course, all the above assumes you are using ES6 with `import` capabilities*

Comment: The section of Vue documentation that describes "asynchronous components" which can achieve lazy loading: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

Comment: Is ES6 enabled by default in browsers? If not, how am I supposed to enable it?

Comment: @saidfagan as you can see here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/
Latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Safari support over 90% of ES6 features, latest version of Microsoft Edge is also fairly good. IE11 would be the one tailing behind for "relevant browser" support if it's a concern. Either way, if you want to be sure you can always use a transpiler like Babel to build down to vanilla compatible Javascript

Comment: That's exactly what I am going to do, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

there are at least 2 ways to achieve what you want, on of them (x-templates) already mentioned by Bill Criswell, but I think it worth to add an example

1. Define your component like this

   `Vue.component('my-checkbox', {
       // id of x-template
       template: '#my-template'
   });`
2. Add html file with your x-template (id should match the one you specified in the component)

   `<script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">...</script>`

Another approach (and I like this one better) would be to use inline template

1. Define your template like this

   `Vue.component('my-template', {});`
2. Add html file with your component and template inside it

   `<my-template inline-template>place for your html</my-template>`

Just don't forget to add `inline-template` attribute, otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach with superagent:

```
var promise = superagent.get("something.html")
    .end(function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.error("load of something.html failed", error));
            return;
        }

        var parser = new DOMParser()
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(response.text, "text/html");
        document.body.appendChild(doc.scripts[0]);
    });
```

Just put your `<script>` tag based template inside of `something.html` on your server.

If you are using jQuery, [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) should work.

Just make sure this completes before the DOM in question is compiled by Vue. Or use [$mount](http://vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#vm-%5C$mount%5C(_%5C[element%5C|selector%5C]_%5C)) to manually set things up.

Answer (score 0):

Use browserify to bundle everything like this:

```
//Home.js

import Vue from 'vue';

var Home = Vue.extend({
    template: require('./Home.vue')
});

export default Home;

//Home.vue
<h1>Hello</h1>

// And for your browserify bundle use a transform called stringify

... .transform(stringify(['.html', '.svg', '.vue', '.template', '.tmpl']));
```