# How to import external template in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am beginner to vue js, not sure i am asking correct or not.

I want to make following type of structure for my Laravel 5.3 - Vue Js App.

1. my-vue.js

   ```
    Vue.component('my-component', {
           template: 'template from Catgory.Vue'
    })

    new Vue({
       el: '#example'
    })
   ```
2. Category.vue

   ```
   <template>
       <div>
           // some code goes here
       </div>
   </template>
   ```
3. index.blade.php

   ```
   <div id="example">
      <my-component></my-component>
   </div>
   ```

   How can i use template from Category.vue in template attribute of Vue.component? Or Suggest me better approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJs templating. How to load external templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633573/vuejs-templating-how-to-load-external-templates)

Comment: do i need to use import or require for loading external template fron category.vue file?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180626211549/https://sebastiandedeyne.com/dealing-with-templates-in-vue-20/) can be useful

```
 Vue.component('my-component', {
   template: require('./Category.html')
 });
 new Vue({
     el: '#example'
 })
```

Category.html.js

```
module.exports = `<div>Hello, {{ name }}!</div>`;
```

Comment: The link in the Answer is dead can anyone update that.

Comment: assumes node js which is not always the case.