# How to use HTML Imports with Vue?

Tags: html, vue.js

I would like to play with [HTML Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports), but I did not found any examples how it can be used with Vue.

Comment: See also: [VueJs templating. How to load external templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633573/vuejs-templating-how-to-load-external-templates).