# Load static HTML files in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to load a static HTML file (of a Jupyter notebook) inside a div in my Vue js app.

I tried doing `<iframe src="/static/product.html">` but this renders the home page of the vue app inside the iframe.

What's the correct way to do this in vue?

Comment: Have a look to this post from vue.js : [Why Vue.js doesn't support templateURL](https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/)

Comment: And here you have a way to do what's you want : [vue component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642208/6796524). It's a bit heavy to load only a static html file, but component approach can handle a lot of other case.

Comment: @Camille It's a 15000 line long file, I tried converting it to a vue file but it makes the whole app sluggish.

Comment: With post provided in my first comment, you should be able to load a html file without converting to a real vue component

Answer (score 3):

Load vue ressource addon if not done already

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.10/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
```

In your app, create a component who load your static raw html page

```
Vue.component('statichtmlpage', function (resolve, reject) {
    vue.$http.get('your_static_html_page.html', function(data, status, request){
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
        resolve({
            template: doc
        });
    });
});
```

And add component tag where you like to display your page

```
<statichtmlpage></statichtmlpage>
```

Comment: I've tried this approach, getting empty HTML <!-- --> in place of the component tag. This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/133660/

Comment: Thanks, I am able to get it working for URLs now. Facing a problem in loading local files. `/static/product.html` the path is correct but leads to an empty doc. Probably because when I hit `localhost:8080/static/product.html` it redirects to home. Am I understanding this correctly? Will mapping the url to the file with vue-router fix this?

Comment: Did you ever get that working...a jupyter html file in a vuejs app @NitinLabhishetty

Comment: Nope, had to use a hack around this. I created a simple node server to serve the static html files and used an iframe in the vuejs app to render them.